# Does the quantifier {0} make sense in some scenarios?

Tags: regex

Example:

/(?:Foo){0}bar/

I saw something like this in another answer. At first I thought "what should that be", but then, "OK could make sense, kind of a negative look behind", so that `Foo` is not allowed before `bar`, but this is not working.

You can see this [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uokr): It matches only `bar` but it matches also the `bar` in `Foobar`.
When I add an anchor for the start of the row:

```
/^(?:Foo){0}bar/
```

it behaves like I expect. It matches only the `bar` and not the `bar` in `Foobar`.

But that's exactly the same behaviour as if I used only `/bar/` or `/^bar/`.

**Is the quantifier `{0}` only a useless side effect, or is there really a useful behaviour for that?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are *good* uses of `{0}`. It allows you to *define groups that you don't intend to capture at the moment*. This can be useful in some cases:

- The best one - use of the group in recursive regular expressions (or other weird constructs). Perl, for example, has [`(?(DEFINE) )`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28DEFINE%29) for the same use.
  A quick example - in PHP, this will match `barFoo` ([working example](http://ideone.com/LIrr1)):

  ```
  preg_match("/(?:(Foo)){0}bar(?1)/", "barFoo", $matches);
  ```
- Adding a failed captured group (named or numbered) to the result matches.
- Keeping the indices of all groups intact in case the pattern was refactored.

Less good uses, as Peter suggested are useful in:

- Generated patterns.
- Readability - Patterns with certain duplication, where `{0}` and `{1}` may lead thinking in the right direction. (OK, not the best point)

These are all rare cases, and in most patterns it is a mistake.

Comment: That's awesome, Kobi. This is only useful in an engine that has subroutines but not `(?(DEFINE))`, I think that's only Ruby and probably Python with the `regex` module. Tested in Ruby: `(?:(Foo)){0}bar\g<1>` +1000!

Comment: In case anyone is interested, not working in Python with `regex` module. But came up with this alternative, which works: `(?:(Foo)$^)?bar(?1)`

Answer (score 3):

An explicit repetition count of zero can be useful in automatically generated regular expressions. You avoid coding a special case for zero repetitions this way.

Answer (score 2):

In traditional regular expressions, `/x{0}/` (language = { x<sup>n</sup> : x = 0}) would mean "match exactly 0 of x", which is the same thing as `//` (language = { Λ }).  Since the two are equivalent, you should be able to remove any `/x{0}/` you find lying around.

But PCREs and other extensions to regular expressions can get quite byzantine.  I would not be surprised if `/x{0}/` did something in Perl.  I would be disgusted, but not surprised.

I think it's probably some artifact of a program that automatically generates regular expressions but doesn't simplify them.  Which is a shame, since it's so easy to write programs that simplify regular expressions.

Comment: _"I would be disgusted, but not surprised."_ :)

Comment: Is it really so easy to write programs that simplify regular expressions? That sounds interesting...

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a single good reason to use `x{0}`. But I can think of several why it should be avoided:

- It's useless since it always matches.
- It slows the regex engine down (unless the regex is precompiled).
- It's probably a sign of misunderstanding by the regex author.

I'm willing to bet that someone who writes `(?:foo){0}` is *trying* to say "make sure that `foo` doesn't match here", which of course fails because the empty string can always be matched, whether `foo` is there or not. That's what negative lookaround assertions are for. `(?<!foo)bar` etc.